# In Apache Tomcat 6 clustering, why does TomcatA call invalidate is on session (S1) when it receives a request?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Referring to the [Apache Tomcat 6 Clustering Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) in the "How it works" section:

> -7. TomcatA receives a request, invalidate is called on the session (S1)
>
> The invalidate is call is intercepted, and the session is queued with
>   invalidated sessions. When the request is complete, instead of sending
>   out the session that has changed, it sends out an "expire" message to
>   TomcatB and TomcatB will invalidate the session as well.
>
> -8. TomcatB receives a request, for a new session (S2)
>
> Same scenario as in step 3)
>
> -9. TomcatA The session S2 expires due to inactivity.
>
> The invalidate is 
>   call is intercepted the same was as when a session is invalidated by
>   the user, and the session is queued with invalidated sessions. At this
>   point, the invalidet session will not be replicated across until
>   another request comes through the system and checks the invalid queue.

Why in step 7, does Tomcat A invalidate session S1? Is the new session S2 related to session S1 in anyway? Why does session S2 expire in step 9?

Answer (score 0):

These are separate scenarios. It's not a numbered list of steps that happen in order. That disposes of two of your questions, and the third is answered by saying there is no relationship between sessions.